# app redirect to Facebook app for log in iphone 5

Tags: facebook, ios6, iphone-5

I have integrated Facebook in ios 6 and it's works perfect 3GS,4 and iPhone 4S but when I test the app with IPhone 5 it just redirect the user to Facebook app log in view if user enters credentials it opens the Facebook app and user not able to go back on the app. it working fine except iphone 5. I have check the Facebook reference app for integration of Facebook in IOS 6. same thing happens with that app also. I am using FacebookSDK 3.1.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

SSO has been very problematic with the openActiveSession... login methods.  It only seems to work using the login methods beginning with:

openWith...

The iOS user switching sample and authentication sample both use the openWith... login methods.  To avoid SSO problems altogether, use:

openWithBehavior:FBSessionLoginBehaviorForcingWebView

This is not the ideal user experience because it circumvents SSO, requiring the user to login even if they are logged in at system level or in the Facebook app, but it works consistently.

Comment: it's not problematic we need to understand the working of SSO tha't all.